# Linking to the most recent post in a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories, links, pods-framework

I found this wonderful code that allows you to create a link to the most recent post in a category, and it's perfect for what I need. I tried it out, it works great. However, it doesn't include posts from Custom Post Types. (I'm using Wordpress Pods plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/ to create my CPTs.) How do I modify this to include the posts from my custom post types? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Original thread: [How can I link to the most recent post in a category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128576/how-can-i-link-to-the-most-recent-post-in-a-category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as Pods creates standard custom post types, you can simply update the [arguments passed to WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) . The`$post_type` parameter will allow you to filter the results based on the specified post type (string) or post types (array).

```
$latest = new WP_Query( array(
    'category_name' => $request->query_vars['category_name'],
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => array ( 'post', 'your_custom_post_type' ),
) );
```