# Linking to the most recent post in my podcast category

Tags: categories, recent-posts, link-category

I am attempting to pulloff what the author did here: [How can I link to the most recent post in a category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128576/how-can-i-link-to-the-most-recent-post-in-a-category)

However, after updating my functions.php file in my child theme I can not get it to load the latest post from the podcast category. When I try:

http://talkdirtytome.show/podcast/?latest

it returns with a list off all the podcast episodes in the podcast category. When I attempt to goto http://talkdirtytome.show/category/podcast/?latest

I get a Nothing Found page. I am sure there has got to be something simple I am missing I just dont know what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code currently in my functions.php file is:

```
function wpa_latest_in_category_redirect( $request ){
    if( isset( $_GET['latest'] )
        && isset( $request->query_vars['category_name'] ) ){

        $latest = new WP_Query( array(
            'category_name' => $request->query_vars['category_name'],
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        ) );
        if( $latest->have_posts() ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $latest->post->ID ) );
            exit;
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpa_latest_in_category_redirect' );
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: ok, code has been added.

Comment: Do you even have a category named "Podcast" in your WordPress because if we go on this page (http://www.talkdirtytome.show/podcast/episode-2-starting-a-business/), on the sidebar, we have "catgories" and you only have "Uncategorized". 

You still looks like having a post type named "Podcase". So I assume your should have a link like this `` http://www.talkdirtytome.show/podcast/?latest `` and work your function about detecing your $_GET and post type equals to podcast. If yes, I can try to work a function for you.

Comment: I am using a plugin called Seriously Simple Podcast. I think that is what is changing the URL structure. In my control panel, it has its own section and none of my podcasts are tied to any categories (as far as I can tell) Here is a screenshot of what I see. Maybe this will help: https://ibb.co/ZN7LnNn

Comment: @PatricePoliquin, That's It! I would like a function to check and load the episode.  So basically when the user enters http://talkdirtytome.show/podcast/?latest then it takes them to the latest episode.

Comment: What do you think @PatricePoliquin? Is this something you could help me with please?