# Add a simple php code snippet to redirect a single wordpress url to another

Tags: redirect

I've been searching for hours now and I can't figure out how to do a simple redirect from a specific url to another.

I usually use the RankMath plugin for redirects, but they have a bug that won't work if the incoming and destion url contains query parameters, they are not merged and produce an invalid url. They wont fix that for now.

But I can do coding, but I could not figure out how to get the current URL.

This is a sample code that works. It redirects `/myspecialcategory?latest` to the latest category. And with rankmath I redirect `/myspecialurl` to `/myspecialcategory?latest`.

```php
// See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/129059/213014
function wpa_latest_in_category_redirect( $request ){
    if( isset( $_GET['latest'] )
        && isset( $request->query_vars['category_name'] ) ){

        $latest = new WP_Query( array(
            'category_name' => $request->query_vars['category_name'],
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        ) );
        if( $latest->have_posts() ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $latest->post->ID ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpa_latest_in_category_redirect' );
```

But since the rankmath plugin has problems with those query parameters, I need to go for a workaround. However **this does not work**. How can I get the incoming url from `$request`? It should not be so hard, but I found not a single resource online.

```php
function redirect_workaround( $request ){
    if( $request->query == 'myspecialurl' ) {

        $latest = new WP_Query( array(
            'category_name' => 'myspecialcategory',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        ) );
        if( $latest->have_posts() ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $latest->post->ID ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'redirect_workaround' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found the solution, it was a simple change in the request object class variable:

```php
function redirect_workaround( $request ){
    if( $request->request === 'myspecialurl' ) {

        $latest = new WP_Query( array(
            'category_name' => 'myspecialcategory',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        ) );
        if( $latest->have_posts() ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $latest->post->ID ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'redirect_workaround' );
```